# Get value before/after submit from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I've a simple form. The form includes a javascript rich editor. All my input-controls use a model except the javascript editor.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Username)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Firstname)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Firstname)

    <textarea class="rich-text-editor">
    </textarea>

   <input type="submit"/>
}
```

After the user writes something into the editor it contains it's content.

```
    <textarea class="rich-text-editor">
        <p>HALLO WORLD</p>
    </textarea>
```

There is also an jQuery function `$(".rich-text-editor").code`

I'm looking for a way to get the content into the controller without a separated ajax call. Is there any possibility.

Comment: why you don't use field for texarea too? If you will use it, that you can submit data from you form a post method

Comment: Example? Maybe answer?

Comment: I am not sure I understood your questions. This is just a hunch `@Html.TextAreaFor(r => r.Content);` Just make sure your model consists of a property named Content.

Comment: Add a property for 'Content' to your model and treat it just like the username and firstname property. Don't forget to add the 'AllowHtml' property on your content property

Comment: The textarea gets converted to div after initialization.

Comment: Add a property called Content to your model, then give the text area an ID and name of Content.

Comment: ah, and you have to read the content with the jQuery function. Then the only thing I can come up with is to hook (with Jquery) a function on the forms' `submit` event, and in that function, with the `$(".rich-text-editor").code` code, put the code in a hidden field (with the name 'content, and then add a property 'content' on your model)

Comment: @MR.ABC: Doesn't matter, the rich text editor is updating the real textarea behind the scenes. It doesn't replace it; it just hides the textarea and renders a div in its place.

Comment: @ChrisPratt How does you know this? Nope it does not! Maybe it hooks to postbacks via js if even possible. It should/can be like this.

Comment: Which jquery rich editor are you using?. Chris is correct. All you need is `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.YourProperty)` and then apply the plugin to the element `$('#YourProperty')...` which hides the `<textarea>` and replaces it with other elements. As you enter text, the hidden textarea is updated and will post back correctly to your model so long as you have applied the `[AllowHtml]` attribute to the property.